# Modular equation system but not linear

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to solve this system of equations and have used the Chinese remainder theorem with the first two equations, but I don't know how to deal with the quadratic term.

\begin{array}{rcl}
x  &\equiv 2 \pmod{5} \\
3x  &\equiv -4 \pmod{11} \\
x^2  &\equiv 1  \pmod{19} 
\end{array}

Comment: Well, what are the square roots of $1\pmod {19}$?

Comment: @lulu there are 1 and 18

Comment: Good, so now set up two systems of simultaneous congruences.  In both use the top two of your three.  Then add $x\equiv \pm 1\pmod {19}$.  You should get two different residue classes $\pmod {5\times 11\times 19}$.

Comment: I see, thank you very much!

Comment: Another way is squaring the first 2, solving $x^2$ and sqrting .

Answer (score 0):

Note that we have
\begin{align*}
x^2 &\equiv 1 \pmod{19}\\
x^2 - 1 &\equiv 0 \pmod{19}\\
(x - 1)(x + 1) &\equiv 0 \pmod{19}\\
x &\equiv \pm 1 \pmod{19}
\end{align*}
Thus we have reduced the quadratic condition to a linear condition, and thus can use Chinese Remainder Theorem. We have
\begin{align*}
3x &\equiv -4 \pmod{11}\\
x &\equiv 6 \pmod{11}
\end{align*}
Solving these, we have
\begin{align*}
x &\equiv 2 \pmod{5}\\
x &\equiv 6 \pmod{11}\\
x &\equiv \pm 1 \pmod{19}\\
\implies x &\equiv 457, 512 \pmod{1045}
\end{align*}